# Where do locally downloaded files go on Cloud Composer?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a DAG that downloads a file from Cloud Storage and saves it to the following path: `/home/airflow/gcs/data/FILENAME.txt`

This file then appears in the Cloud Composer storage bucket under `/data`.

However, when I originally wrote the DAG I didn't specify the download location to be: `/home/airflow/gcs/data/` and simply had it downloading the file in place. I would like to go delete those files but I don't know where to find them.

Where do downloaded files in Cloud Composer reside when you don't specify the folder?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't need to worry about cleanup from when you first wrote the DAG - if you're using the `gcs_download_operator`, then according to its [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/891a90665c9be363600fda360f903a6e369ac718/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_download_operator.py#L46-L49), if you did not specify a value for the `filename` parameter, the downloaded file won't be stored on the local file system.

Comment: In this case I wasn't using the `gcs_download_operator` but will check that out going forward. Theoretically speaking though, if I were to download a file to Cloud Composer without specifying `/home/airflow/gcs/data/`...where does it end up?

Comment: What are you using to do the download now? gsutil in a bash operator? Something else?

Comment: I'm using the Google python client and in the documentation they have a method called `download_to_filename`, found here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/cloud-client/snippets.py

This job was originally ran locally and I've basically copied the python into a PythonOperator to run. That's why before it'd download locally, but now I'm just trying to understand what happens when it executes the same code in Composer.